# Bootstrap Fixed navbar is pushing up on only one of my pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have something in the following css that is causing my fixed navbar to push up *when scrolling down* untill its almost not visible. This navbar works on all my other pages so I know its something to do with the following css to this page. Attached is the nav bar css and the css that seems to be causing it to not work properly for (1) page... it seems to work fine in browser and Dreamweaver live view but not on any cell phone... The footer seems jacked now too.. its something in between the header and footer ; Also attached is the pages HTML.

[live version](http://www.zachnewberry.com/test)   as you can see the pages I have finished scroll properly except services > roofing page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Roofing Contractor Springfield IL Surrounding Areas</title>
<meta name="description" content="Licensed Roofing Contractor serving Springfield IL and surrounding areas. Hire a professional and let us exceed your residential roofing needs today!">
<meta name="keywords" content="Roofing Contractor New Roof Repair Licensed Bonded Insured Free Estimates">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav">
<div class="container" id="custom-nav">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com" class="navbar-brand" aria-label="ZNC Roofing Contractor Springfield IL"></a>
</div>
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li>
<a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/about.html">About</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/roofingcontractor.html">Roofing</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/sidingcontractor.html">Siding</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/contact.html">Contact</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.zachnewberry.com/test/careers.html">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="social">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ZachNewberryConstruction"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/ZN_Construction"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+ZachNewberryConstructionTaylorville"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid margin-top">
    <div class="row padding-left padding-right">
        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-color"></span> Roofing Contractor <br><small>"Get The Free Estimate You Deserve!"</small></h3><hr>
        <h4>Need a New Roof or Roof Repairs?<br><small>We are completely Licensed Bonded and Insured for all of your roofing needs!</small></h4>

    </div>
    <hr>
  <div class="row  ">
            <div class="col-md-4 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
                            <img class="lib-img-show" alt="New Roof - Shingle Roofing" src="images/shingle-roofing.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">
                                Shingle Roofing
                                <div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                Shingle Roofing Info Here!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
                            <img class="lib-img-show" alt="New Roof - Rubber Roofing" src="images/flat-roofing.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">
                                Rubber Roofing
                                <div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                Rubber Roofing Info Here
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 no-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
                            <img class="lib-img-show" alt="New Roof - Metal Roofing" src="images/metal-roofing.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">
                                Metal Roofing
                                <div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                                Metal Roofing Info Here!
           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 call-now">
<h4>“We pride ourselves on being able to provide Safe, Clean, Quality work with competitive rates!”</h4>
<a href="tel:+12178207597" class="btn btn-success btn-callnow" role="button">Call Now (217) 820-7597</a>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <small>Copyright © ZNC Roofing Contractor 2017</small>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-91438053-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- Google Maps -->



</body>
</html>
```

Custom Navbar

```
.navbar-collapse {border-color: #FFFFFF !important; margin-top: 5px;}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {color : #FFFFFF  !important;}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{color : #EF7800  !important;}
.navbar-toggle {background: #192F42; padding-top: 12px;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {border-color: #192F42;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {background: none;}
#custom-nav { margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;}
.navbar-inverse {background-color: #192F42;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #192F42}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #192F42}
.dropdown-menu { background-color: #192F42}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-color: #192F42}
.navbar-inverse { background-image: none; }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-image: none;}
.navbar-inverse { border-color: #192F42}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {height: 50px;width: 142px;background: url(../images/brand.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #EF7800}
.dropdown-menu>li>a { color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #EF7800}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #EF7800}





/* Roofing Page */
.lib-panel {
    margin-bottom: 20Px;
}
.lib-panel img {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.lib-panel .row,
.lib-panel .col-md-6 {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


.lib-panel .lib-row {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
}

.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-header .lib-header-seperator {
    height: 2px;
    width: 26px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 7px 0 7px 0;
}

.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-desc {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.lib-panel .lib-row.lib-desc a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
}

.row-margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.10);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.10);
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Formatted link & code

Comment: @zach, can you create a minimal example on fiddle or bootply?

Comment: I have fixed this, thank you for your response! It was something within the panels.. I initially tried to just insert a clean snippet from a website to save time. Eventually I made them myself without error